# Unexpected values in Django admin dropdown when using multiple foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-south

Below is my `models.py`. The problem is that in admin panel the `User` column in the `Ingredience` model points to `Ingredience Category` values instead of `User` values.

In the `Ingredience` model I have **2 foreign keys**. I'm not sure if this is the problem.

**Screenshot from admin panel:**

[image]

**Models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class IngredienceCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Ingredience Categories"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Ingredience(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    category = models.ForeignKey(IngredienceCategory, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
         verbose_name_plural = "Ingredients"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredience)
    html_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Foods"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Any ideas what's the problem here? Here are the steps I've taken before this problem occured:

- I added `user` column to all 3 models and ran the south migration
- After that I manually inserted values to the user column in all 3 tables
- Models `IngredienceCategory` and `Food` work fine (i.e. displaying list of users in the `User` dropdown list
- Here is the SQL: http://pastebin.com/3mHpXA3F

**EDIT:**
Something to add (might be helpful for solving this issue): I noticed that clicking on the plus sign (+) next to the User column in the Ingredience Model in the admin panel, a pop-up form to add new user is displayed, which is correct.

**EDIT 2:**
Relevant part of admin.py file:

```
class IngredienceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name',)
    list_filter = ('category',)
    ordering = ('name',)

#    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
#        #if db_field.name == 'ingrediencecategory':
#        kwargs['queryset'] = IngredienceCategory.objects.order_by('name')
#        return super(IngredienceAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'ingrediencecategory':
            kwargs['queryset'] = IngredienceCategory.objects.order_by('name')
            return super(IngredienceAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

        if db_field.name == 'user':
            kwargs['queryset'] = User.objects.order_by('name')
            return super(IngredienceAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your admin model look like?

Your models look fine and I don't see why you would have this issue. You can have multiple foreign keys in one model, it's normal.

I threw them into a project to take a look (with a blank admin model), and I couldn't reproduce this.

Comment: I added the content of admin.py to the original question.

Comment: I'm really sorry, originally I added wrong admin.py file. There is now correct file added (see EDIT 2).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. If anybody comes across similar problem, here is the working solution (admin.py):

```
class IngredienceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name',)
    list_filter = ('category',)
    ordering = ('name',)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'ingrediencecategory':
            kwargs['queryset'] = IngredienceCategory.objects.order_by('name')

        if db_field.name == 'user':
            kwargs['queryset'] = User.objects.order_by('username')

        return super(IngredienceAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```